# FindElement by XPath: nested divs/ classes

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing the problem with grabbing an element/ elements. I got list of products with "Amount" value, between that field there are two buttons: "-" and "+" which increases the total amount of that field.

What I need to grab are both: plus or minus in order to test it correctly. I've already did it by css selector, however right now there is a need doing it by XPath.

```
var increaseIngredientButton = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-ingredient-list > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3)"));
```

And here is the HTML snippet: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zsQ.png)

First, I need to find the proper row - **product-ingredient-row** (there are many rows of specific products), differentiate it by it name - **product ingredient-name** (name is unique), and finally choose div with either plus or minus. Can someone tell me how it should be done because, unfortunately no idea...

What's more, it's better to use XPath or Cssselectors? Is there a possibility to grab slightly everything with XPath?

```
<div class="product-details-container">
   <div class="product-details-header">
      <div class="product-details-name">Berlusconi</div>
      <div class="product-details-price">
      </div>
      <div class="product-details-total-price">
         <div>Total: </div>
         <div>
            <!-- react-text: 3872 -->11.90<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3873 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-details-close"></span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="product-details-scrollable-area">
      <div class="product-details-allergenics">
         <div>Allergenics:</div>
         <div>None</div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-details-description-expander">
         <div>
            <div style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
               <div style="padding: 16px; font-weight: 500; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; white-space: nowrap; cursor: pointer;">
                  <div style=><span style="></span></div>
                  <button tabindex="0" type="button" style=>
                     <div>
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style=">
                           <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z"></path>
                        </svg>
                     </div>
                  </button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-ingredient-row header">
         <div class="product-ingredient-name">Ingredients:</div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-price">Unit price:</div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">Amount:</div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-ingredient-list">
         <div class="product-ingredient-row">
            <div class="product-ingredient-name">Kotipizza-juusto</div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-price">
               <!-- react-text: 3908 -->0.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3909 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">
               <div>−</div>
               <div>1</div>
               <div>+</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-row">
            <div class="product-ingredient-name">tomaattikastike</div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-price">
               <!-- react-text: 3926 -->0.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3927 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">
               **<div>−</div>
               <div>1</div>
               <div>+</div>**
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-row">
            <div class="product-ingredient-name">kantarelli</div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-price">
               <!-- react-text: 3962 -->0.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3963 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">
               <div>−</div>
               <div>1</div>
               <div>+</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-row">
            <div class="product-ingredient-name">savuporo</div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-price">
               <!-- react-text: 3971 -->0.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3972 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">
               <div>−</div>
               <div>1</div>
               <div>+</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-row">
            <div class="product-ingredient-name">punasipuli</div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-price">
               <!-- react-text: 3980 -->0.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3981 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">
               <div>−</div>
               <div>1</div>
               <div>+</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="product-ingredient-row">
            <div class="product-ingredient-name">pizzapohja, runsaskuituinen</div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-price">
               <!-- react-text: 3989 -->0.00<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 3990 --> €<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="product-ingredient-quantity-container">
               <div>−</div>
               <div>1</div>
               <div>+</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <button class="add-ingredient-btn" tabindex="0" type="button" style=>
         <div><span style=>Add Ingredient</span></div>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="product-details-actions">
      <div style=>
         <button tabindex="0" type="button" style=>
            <div>
               <div style=>Add to cart</span></div>
            </div>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know what portion of HTML is relevant or "enough", in my opinion "only" that which I've enclosed in the screenshot. I need to rewrite the whole snippet into text? (First post here, sorry if something is not as it should be)

Comment: Just like the way you opened the HTML, copy the HTML and paste it within the question area. You being a first timer some of our volunteer may help you out to indent the HTML without which providing a solution would be tough.

Comment: Done, I've deleted style info to reduce the amount of letters

Comment: Awesome, now for which `product-ingredient-name` would you like to increase/decrease quantity? i.e `+` or `-`

Comment: it does not matter : ). Lets say, from product "Berluscioni" I would like to increase an amount of e.g Kotipizza-juusto ingredient

Comment: **It does matter** as questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh, that's fine. I just thought that the code will be almost the same, just the value of the class: "product-ingredient-name" will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, you need to get the row by name. To do so by xpath, use the following xpath:

```
IWebElement rowByName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='punasipuli']"));
```

This will return that div.

Then the + and - are nested within siblings of this element. So what you can do now is:

```
var plusDiv = rowByName.FindElement(By.XPath("..//div[text()='+']"));
var minusDiv = rowByName.FindElement(By.XPath("..//div[text()='-']"));
```

What you are doing here is, with `..` you are going to the parent element (which is `<div class="product-ingredient-row">`), then within that div you are looking for a div on any level with text + or -. As there is only 1 div with a + or 1 div with a -, you will always get the element you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works perfectly... So first of all you're checking for specific div (// - means that we're looking for particular node) which encloses text (input), div you're getting is "product-ingredient-name" then by ".." your're getting parent div which is product-ingredient-row and than looking for text. It's really awesome Anand!

Comment: Will there be a possibility to somehow merge those two commands? [//div[text()='salaatti'..//div[text()='+']?

Comment: I think you just almost did it. If my XPath is correct, it should be: //div[text()='punasipuli']/..//div[text()='+']" - What you are doing here is, you are first getting the div with text punasipuli, then immedietly you are getting its parent with the .. and after that within the parent you are looking for a div with text +